# Nested form hide and show div using Cocoon jQuery callbacks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon in my ruby on rails 4 app to handle my nested form. On one of my nested forms, I give the user the ability to add multiple contacts, and if that contact is marked with a yes in the is_personal_guarantor field, I would like to display more inputs that are inside a div. I want to make sure if the user triggers the div in one nested form, that it won't affect the other nested forms of the same object on the page.

```
# Form
<div id="business_contact">
    <%= f.fields_for :business_contacts, :wrapper => true do |contact_form| %>
        <%= render 'business_contact_fields', :f => contact_form %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association "Add a contact", f, :business_contacts %>
</div>

# business_contact_fields partial
<div class="nested-fields">        
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Input fields -->
            <%= f.select :is_personal_guarantor, options_for_select([["Select", ""], ["Yes", TRUE], ["No", FALSE]], disabled: [""]) %>
        </div>
        <div class="guarantor_details">
            <!-- Input fields -->
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

# jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#business_contact')
    .on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_contact) {
       $(".guarantor_details").hide();
       // Logic to be added
    })
});
```

I understand the added_contact argument in the function is what I need to use, I just don't know how to run if/else logic on it to display the guarantor_details div. I've gotten this far by using the [cocoon docs](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but you can try something like this:

Give a class to the `select` helper:

```
<%= f.select :is_personal_guarantor, options_for_select([["Select", ""], ["Yes", TRUE], ["No", FALSE]], disabled: [""]), class: 'personal-guarantor' %>
```

in JS:

```
$('.personal-guarantor').on('select', function() {

  selectedValue = $(this).val();
  guarantorDetails = $(this).closest('.guarantor_details');

  if(selectedValue == TRUE) { guarantorDetails.hide(); } 
  else { guarantorDetails.show(); }

});
```